# How to force ListView to Invalidate

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I'm new to Android development, I've studied the posts of this site and have tried many different suggestions but still can't solve the problem.

I refer [here](http://ericharlow.blogspot.hk/2010/10/experience-android-drag-and-drop-list.html) to implement the drop-&-drop list view (i.e. user can long-press and drag the list item to reorder the position.  I created a custom ListView, a Adapter and a ListActivity.  Here is part of the code of ListActivity:

```
public class DragNDropListActivity extends ListActivity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.dragndroplistview);

    ArrayList<String> content = new ArrayList<String>(mListContent.length);
    for (int i=0; i < mListContent.length; i++) {
        content.add(mListContent[i]);
    }

    setListAdapter(new DragNDropAdapter(this, new int[]{R.layout.dragitem}, new int[]{R.id.TextView01}, content));//new DragNDropAdapter(this,content)
    ListView listView = getListView();

    if (listView instanceof DragNDropListView) {
        ((DragNDropListView) listView).setDropListener(mDropListener);
        ((DragNDropListView) listView).setRemoveListener(mRemoveListener);
        ((DragNDropListView) listView).setDragListener(mDragListener);
    }

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.i("", "OnItemClick");
        }
    });

}

private DropListener mDropListener = 
    new DropListener() {
    public void onDrop(int from, int to) {
        ListAdapter adapter = getListAdapter();
        if (adapter instanceof DragNDropAdapter) {
            ((DragNDropAdapter)adapter).onDrop(from, to);
            getListView().invalidateViews();
        }
    }
};
```

My problem is: 
When I dragged & dropped an item to a new position, it was replaced properly. But after that, when I tried to drag that item again, the previous item in that position was shown. This problem could be recovered if I put the App into background and then put it back again.

Inside "onDrop", the list view is invalidated.  I've learned from this site that invalidateViews() does not run immediately, but it seems that invalidateViews() never run until I put the App into the background ?!  How can I force the list view to redraw itself ?

More information: the App ran properly in emulator but this problem happened in my Galaxy phone (4.1.2).

Hope somebody could help, many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Check This if it works :

```
private DropListener mDropListener = 
new DropListener() {
public void onDrop(int from, int to) {
    ListAdapter adapter = getListAdapter();
    if (adapter instanceof DragNDropAdapter) {
       ((DragNDropAdapter)adapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
        ((DragNDropAdapter)adapter).onDrop(from, to);
         getListView().invalidate();

    }
}
```

};

Comment: Thanks Ritaban, still no luck !

Comment: The notifyDataSetChanged() should come after the onDrop() since data is updated inside onDrop.